# OpenDroneMap returns error on merging depthmaps?

Tags: ubuntu, linux, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, opendronemap

I am doing a reconstruction on 424 Parrot Sequoia RGB images using OpenDroneMap.  The reconstruction runs for about 2 hours then throws the  error shown below. I have successfully done several reconstructions using ODM on my computer but I have never seen this problem.

I am running ODM on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Load and prepare mesh: 
PLY Loader: comment PCL generated
Reading PLY: 52843 verts... 105614 faces... done.
Warning: Zero-length normals detected: 12 face normals, 0 vertex     normals
Generating texture views: 
NVM: Loading file...
NVM: Number of views: 424
NVM: Number of features: 0
        Loading 53%...libpng error: Write Error                                 
Aborted (core dumped)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gerry/OpenDroneMap-v0.4/run.py", line 47, in <module>
    plasm.execute(niter=1)
  File "/home/gerry/OpenDroneMap-v0.4/scripts/mvstex.py", line 139,     in process
        '{keepUnseenFaces}'.format(**kwargs))
  File "/home/gerry/OpenDroneMap-v0.4/opendm/system.py", line 34, in run
raise Exception("Child returned {}".format(retcode))
Exception: Child returned 134
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this was not an issue with OpenDroneMap.  My computer ran out of physical memory.  Deleting/moving other files freed memory and allowed me to finish the reconstruction.